# Cocos2D 0.99.5 CCDirector pixel format?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iphone, pixelformat

I'm trying to set the pixel format in my CCDirector but i can't find the method.

It seems to me that my version of cocos2d doesn't have that method??

Strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app delegate, look for this line:

```
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];
```

or search for

```
EAGLView *glView
```

and you will find it..